MSBUILD Error MSB4801 even when using RoslynCodeTaskFactory on Azure Devops
I am getting this error even when using the RoslynCodeTaskFactory in my props file. The project builds on my local machine, but not on Azure Devops. How do I fix this so it builds on Azure?

Error MSB4801: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild.

I have read this StackOverflow post as well.
Here is my UsingTask:
    <UsingTask TaskName="CheckFileAge"
            TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory"
            AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll" >
        <ParameterGroup>
            <FilePath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
            <IsOlder ParameterType="System.Boolean" Output="true" />
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Using Namespace="System" />
            <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                <![CDATA[
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    if (!fileInfo.Directory.Exists) {
        fileInfo.Directory.Create();
    }

    // Ensure the file exists
    if (!fileInfo.Exists) {
        // create the file, and release the lock. also sets the LastWriteTime
        using (fileInfo.Create()) { }
        IsOlder = true;
    } else {
        var fileTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(FilePath);
        IsOlder = (DateTime.Now - fileTime).TotalHours > 1;
    }
                    
    if (IsOlder) {
        // lets touch the file now, so we will skip deploying for N hours
        fileInfo.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
]]>
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>

More Info:

Image: windows-latest
.Net Core Version (8.x): 8.0.404

Local Machine:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.12.1
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.12.1+35514.174
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032
Installed Version: Professional

Dotnet sdks

3.1.426
5.0.408
6.0.428
8.0.404
9.0.100





EDIT: Posting these images for clarity. As you can see the SHAs match. With the change to the correct task factory.

The build error

The commit



If need be, I can provide my yaml as well.

I couldn't replicate your error. I added your UsingTask to a project file and successfully built with Visual Studio 2022 v17.12.3. I don't believe that the MSB4801
error is from the UsingTask that you shared, because the type of the task factory is a format item in the error message string and the error message you shared is not reporting Error MSB4801: The task factory "RoslynCodeTaskFactory" ....

It is NOT Visual Studio. I can build fine there. Its when it builds on Azure Devops only.

It all of a sudden started building on Azure late Friday afternoon EST. No code changes. No yaml changes. Magic? Hmmm or the error got fixed?
